# FileMaker Pie Chart Labels Overlapping

Tags: charts, filemaker

FileMaker seems to do pie charts with evenly distributed data points very well. While the styling options are limited in comparison to Excel, it still gets the job done. However with undistributed data it's another story. For example, if one item on the pie chart takes up 95% of the room, and five other items take up the remaining 5%, you get this:

[image]

Notice how the labels for those five items all overlap? I was wondering if there was a way around this?

Comment: I believe the best solution would be to aggregate all categories below some threshold under a common "Other" label. If these categories are not known in advance, you will have to script this.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I think, most of the charting programs will struggle to output data point labels correctly in this case, even if you can display them at an angle, which you can't do in FileMaker.

You can remove data point labels by making font colour the same as the background or transparent in Chart Setup/Styles/Chart Text or by unchecking Chart Setup/Chart/Options/"Show values on chart". Instead you can enable legend by checking "Chart Setup"/Chart/Options/"Show Legend"

If it is not enough, you might consider using one of JavaScript libraries in WebViewer to display your chart (e.g. HighCharts).

I checked setup on FileMaker 13, so 14 Chart Setup dialogue could be slightly different.

Comment: I figured that was the case, FileMaker's chart options seem painfully limited compared to Excel. We had considered the WebView option already as well. Thanks for confirming that.